# Why are files checked out to previous changesets appearing in the index as modified?

Tags: git

```
D:\code\gt>git init
Initialized empty Git repository in D:/code/gt/.git/

D:\code\gt>echo Zero > a

D:\code\gt>git add a

D:\code\gt>git commit -m a
[master (root-commit) 392580e] a
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 a

D:\code\gt>echo One > a

D:\code\gt>git add a

D:\code\gt>git commit -m another
[master 271efba] another
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 1 deletions(-)

D:\code\gt>echo Second > a

D:\code\gt>git add a

D:\code\gt>git commit -m "yet another"
[master 8d2041e] yet another
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 1 deletions(-)

D:\code\gt>git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)

D:\code\gt>git checkout  271ef a

D:\code\gt>git status
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       modified:   a
#
```

As you can see, I checkout the file in the state it had at the 2nd commit. However, I don't understand why it's already added to the index. Why isn't git letting me do the add?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a point which isn't entirely clear from the [`git checkout` documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout), so it's a good question.

When you do:

```
git checkout COMMIT -- PATH
```

... the working copy **and** the index for `PATH` are updated with the version from `COMMIT`.  So, relative to `HEAD`, there are indeed changes to that file staged after running that command.